# Is the actor model limited to specific languages?

Tags: scala, architecture, erlang, actor

I was reading an [interesting blog post](http://smyck.net/2012/04/22/why-erlang/) about Erlang/OTP and the actor model. I also hear that Scala supports the actor model. From the little I gathered so far, the actor model breaks down processing into components that communicate with each other by passing messages. Typically, those processes are immutable.

Are those features language-specific though or more at the architecture level? more specifically, can't you just implement the same actor model in almost any language, and just use some form of message-queue to pass messages between worker processes? (for example, use something like [celery](http://celeryproject.org/)). Or is it that those languages like Erlang and Scala simply do this transparently and [much faster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3358044/305019)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Certainly you can define an "Actor Library" in virtually any language, but in Erlang the model is baked-in to the language, and is really the only concurrency model available.

While Scala's actors system is well implemented,  at the end of the day, it still vulnerable to some hazards that Erlang is immune from.  I'll draw your attention to this [paper](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2009/HPL-2009-148.pdf).

This would be the case for any Actor library implemented in any imperative language that supports shared mutable state.

An interesting exception to this is Nodes.js. Some work is being done with actors between Nodes that probably exhibit the same isolation properties as Erlang, simply because there is no shared mutable state.

Comment: Thanks @dsmith. That's interesting. So if I understand this, the shared mutable state is the primary source of issues. As far as I see it, any message-queue based architecture that passes serialized tasks/data to worker processes should therefore pretty much be immune to that. Does it therefore make it compatible with the actor model? Can one therefore assume that e.g. celery already implements the actor model?

Comment: The key is isolation of mutable state.  Erlang isolates mutable state in light-weight processes.  Nodes state would be isolated in OS processes with a single thread of execution.  And, yes, messaging solutions such as celery/rabbitmq would exhibit the same qualities.

Comment: Thanks again. I accepted your answer (together with the extra info provided by @talg, which really made it complete for me). Got a much better picture now about erlang, and yet useful to know that the actor model can still be implemented (albeit in a somewhat limited form) with something like python/celery/rabbitmq etc.

Answer (score 3):

Actor model is **not** limited to any specific platform or programming language, it's just a model after all.

Erlang and Scala have really good and useful implementations of this model, which fits nicely in typical technology stack of these platforms and helps to effectively solve certain kinds of tasks.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the points mentioned above, the fact that in Erlang actor model is the only way you can program, makes your code scalable from the get-go. Erlang processes are lightweight, and you can spawn 10-100K on one machine (I don't think you can do it with python), this changes the way you approach problems. For example, in our product we parse web server logs with Erlang and spawn an Erlang process to handle each line. That way, if one log line is corrupted, or the process that handles it crashes, nothing happens to the other ones. 
Another difference is when you start using OTP you get processes supervisors and you can make processes connected so if one terminates all the others do. 
Other than that, Erlang has some other nice feature (which can be found in other languages through libraries, but again here it's baked in) like pattern matching and hot deploy.

Comment: Indeed, the fact that the actor implementation is built on extremely light-weight processes and that you can quickly spawn hundreds of thousands of these actor units in a single OS process, makes Erlang unique.  Other implementations that use heavy-weight OS processes or threads are limited.

Comment: Joining those two answers together I get a much clearer picture now. Spawning a process for each log line sounds crazy, but it seems like a very good illustration to a massive change in approaching problems. Certainly not something I would even try in python. And I do agree that being *forced* by the language to only work this way can be advantageous. Thanks to both for making things much clearer!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing language-specific about the Actor Model. In fact, you already mention Scala in your question, where actors are not part of the language but are instead implemented as a library. (Three competing libraries, actually.)

However, just like Functional Programming or Object-Oriented Programming, having direct support for Actor Programming, or at least support for some abstractions that make it easier to implement, in the language will lead to a very different programming experience. Anyone who has ever done Functional Programming or Object-Oriented Programming in C will probably understand this.

Comment: I think your analogy to using OOP principals in C programmes is a good one. It's unfortunate the Scala chose to allow unconstrained mutable state. Something more akin to clojure's references would have suited Scala better -- but may have raised the bar to entry for the average Java developer.